# How do I perform collision tests between two 3D oriented bounding boxes?

Tags: 3d, collision-detection, bullet-physics

I want to test two 3D oriented bounding box objects against each other and stop them if there is a hit detected.

How can I accomplish this using only the collision detection functions in the Bullet physics API?

Comment: Look at the first sample in bullet source, App_BasicDemo, it does exactly this (collision between non-AA boxes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bullet comes with many demos, some of them just show or uses exactly what you want to achieve.

I suggest to have a look at the Bullet demos.

The demos folder should be right in the root of the Bullet source code.

You can browse the code online here https://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

Comment: that demo uses the physics engine which is don't want to use.

Comment: @user389006 bullet is a physics library, if you do not want to use physics why using this library? i don't get your point and what you want to achieve.

Comment: i want to manage all the movement myself. should i use an other library for collision detection?

Comment: @user389006 just run the demos, you will controll the subject, the collision detection doesn't care about controlling the movement, you will control the player with your input, the point about a collision detection system is just to trigger an event when and if 2 or more meshes or parts of a mesh are in contact, nothing to do with controlling the movements, you can also find some articles online http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php?title=Documentation , just run the demos and you will see everything by yourself.